# Calculate the Lebesgue integral $\int f_j d\lambda$ for every $j\in \{1, 2, 3\}$

Tags: calculus, integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Consider functions $f_1, f_2, f_3 : \mathbb R \rightarrow \left[0, \infty\right)$

$$f_1\left(x\right)=x^2 \\ f_2\left(x\right)=\frac{1}{1+x^2} \\ f_3\left(x\right)= \text{e}^{-|x|}$$
for all $x$ in $\mathbb R$.

I want to calculate the Lebesgue integral $\int f_j \ d\lambda$ for every $j\in \{1, 2, 3\}$.

I know I can use the following:
$$\int f \ \textbf{1}_\left[-n, n\right] \ \text{d}\mu \ \uparrow \ \int f \ \text{d}\mu$$
for $n\rightarrow \infty$. But I don't know how I do it. I will really appreciate it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The first one looks quite big. Might be even infinite.

Comment: How can you see that?

Comment: For $x>1$ you have $x^2>1$.

Comment: Are you familiar how to calculate these as Riemann integrals? They are equivalent in this case since the functions are continuous.

Comment: I think I have figured it out.

Comment: The first one gives $\infty$, the second one gives $\pi$ and the third one gives $\infty$?

Comment: @TarekBadr The third integral is not $\infty$. It is equal to $2$.